# Is there a way to import existing Sonar Rules in Local sonar setup

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I'm trying to run a local instance of sonar http://localhost:9000/projects to do a sonar check in my local. This check I want to do with the existing rule in my organisation sonar. I can import the rule and try to restore it in local sonar but it doesn't import all the rules. This is a known bug in Sonar https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-5366 but wanted to know if there is a workaround to replicate all the rules in local instance.

Comment: Did you try to use a backup of the production database (won't work for paid versions/plugins)?

Comment: What do you mean by "production database" in Sonar terms? If you mean quality profile defined in our organization central sonar then yes I did. While importing Those rule in Local Sonar setup its not importing all.

Comment: The organizational central SonarQube instance is storing the (historical) results found in a database. If it is possible to create a backup of that database you could restore that database on you local instance and use that.